# SQLite compare single value to multiple values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following:

```
DELETE from myTable where someNum = (select someNum from difTable);
```

My issue is that "`select someNum from difTable`" return values `1,3` which it should however I am only removing rows that have values `someNum = 1.`

How do I get it to run against all values returned from my select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the first value back - use the IN instead of = operator:

```
DELETE from myTable where someNum in (select someNum from difTable);
```